# How to overlay a <div>

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, html

how to overlay a  to do this effect in the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVVgY.png)

in case, I want the logo to stay above the navbar

at the moment, it is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GxVT.png)

in the code looks like this:

```
 <!-- menu de navegação -->
<div class="header sticky-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <nav class="menu1 navbar navbar-expand-md">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse_target">
    <div class="col-md-3 divlogo">
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-12">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'home')?>" class="nav-link">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">ENCOMENDAS</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">CURSOS</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">VIDEOAULAS</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">BOLO NO POTE</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">CONTATO</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>

<!-- banner -->
<section class="sec0">
    <div class="banner1 col-12 img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="text1 col-xs-12">
    <div class="logoresponsive row" style="z-index: 9999;">
    <div class="col col-lg-16">
        <a href="index.php"><img id="logo" style="margin-top: -140%; z-index: 9999;" class="logo1 logo img-fluid navbar-brand" alt="responsive image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/img/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

in which the Logo I want to place on top of the navbar is id = "logo"

Answer (score 0):

Set your positioning to abolute (with `position: absolute;`) on the logo, and the Z-index property will take that effect what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the parent. Check more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_parent_child.asp)

Fist of all, you need to close all the tags:

```
<!-- menu de navegação -->
<div class="header sticky-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="menu1 navbar navbar-expand-md">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse_target">
                    <div class="col-md-3 divlogo">
                    </div>
                    <div class=" col-md-12">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'home')?>" class="nav-link">HOME</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">ENCOMENDAS</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">CURSOS</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">VIDEOAULAS</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">BOLO NO POTE</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">CONTATO</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- banner -->
<section class="sec0">
    <div class="banner1 col-12 img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text1 col-xs-12">
                <div class="logoresponsive row" style="z-index: 9999;">
                    <div class="col col-lg-16">
                        <a href="index.php"><img id="logo" style="margin-top: -140%; z-index: 9999;" class="logo1 logo img-fluid navbar-brand" alt="responsive image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/img/logo.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Then, instead of editing your image style (which is the child), edit the section tag (the parent). It would like this:

**Note:** z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

```
<section class="sec0" style="position: absolute;margin-top: -200px; z-index: -1;">
```

I don't know exactly what you want to do but this way you'll have the image on the background and the text above it.

Hope this helps.